# Why doesn't the JS strict mode work in Q Promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I'm new to most of what is to follow - so I'm pretty sure I'm missing something fundamental.

This is causing me a lot of debugging-grief but for some reason strict mode is not enforced inside promise call back methods:

```
"use strict";
const Q = require("q");
Q(3).then(function(x){console.log(abc);})
setTimeout(function(){console.log("done!")}, 5000);
```

All I get on the console is after 5 seconds is `done!`

Now if I had done:

```
"use strict";    
console.log(abc);
```

I would get `ReferenceError: abc is not defined`

What's going on?  How come strict-mode is not respected?

---

Update as soon as I posted I figured it out (new to promises).

I had not catch block.  So this works as expected

```
Q(3)
    .then(function(x){log.info(abc);})
    .catch(function(x){log.error(x);});`
```

Comment: Yep, errors inside promise handlers are converted to promise rejections. You should post your answer in the answers section.

Comment: `process.on("unhandledRejection", e => {throw e;})` thank me later or use a library like bluebird :D